# Gather and Scatter intrinsics in the Loop Vectorizer with llvm

Tags: clang, llvm, avx512

I am trying to generate scatter/gather example in with llvm with no success. I am running the next example as mentioned in the llvm [doc](https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html#scatter-gather):

```
int foo(int * A, int * B, int n) {
  for (intptr_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      A[i] += B[i * 4];
}
```

I am compiler with the next command line:

```
clang ./test.cpp -save-temps -O3 -march=skylake-avx512 -mllvm -force-vector-width=512
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Pick a loop that would benefit from gather/scatter!  That one wouldn't; there's lots of known overlap between input and output, so the optimal vectorization would do one vector from `A` and shuffle together 4 vectors from `B` (hopefully with two `vpermt2d` instructions).

Comment: Classic gather is something like a LUT like `A[i] += B[index[i]]`.  For scatter as well, a histogram, like `counts[values[i]] ++;` could work, but that requires conflict detection.  IDK if compilers will auto-vec that.

Comment: This does use `vpgatherqd`: https://godbolt.org/z/YohdFT (only into 16 byte registers, though) -- I assume the argument to `-force-vector-width` is the number of scalars, not the bit-width. But as @Peter, I'm also not convinced this is really the best solution here ...

Comment: @chtz: Oh weird, I hadn't checked the OP's asm output.  With `-O3 -march=skylake-avx512 -mprefer-vector-width=512`, we do get the expected `vpermt2d` vectorization (https://godbolt.org/z/ih_Agf).  The `vshufi64x2` instructions could maybe be avoided by writing the high half with a merge-masked `vpermt2d` with a different shuffle control.  Anyway, apparently `-force-vector-width=512` has some surprising effects that should maybe get reported as missed-optimization bugs.  It does look like it's element width, 512 gives a hugely unrolled loop.

Comment: Interesting. What's even worse about the `-force-vector-width` variant is that it adds a constant offset to each index register, instead of simply increasing `rsi`. But it also seems to implement wrap-around behavior for `4*i`, instead of exploiting the undefinedness of signed integer overflow (that can be avoided by using `long i` and `long n`, or by multiplying with `4LL` -- but  `-mprefer-vector-width=512` looks superior here, indeed).